# Distributing jobs evenly across multiple GPUs with `multiprocessing.Pool`

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say that I have the following:

- A system with 4 GPUs.
- A function, `foo`, which may be run up to 2 times simultaneously on each GPU.
- A list of `files` that need to be processed using `foo` in any order. However, each file takes an unpredictable amount of time to be processed.

I would like to process all the files, keeping all the GPUs as busy as possible by ensuring there are always 8 instances of `foo` running at any given time (2 instance on each GPU) until less than 8 files remain.

The actual details of invoking the GPU are not my issue. What I'm trying to figure out is how to write the parallelization so that I can keep 8 instances of `foo` running but somehow making sure that exactly 2 of each GPU ID are used at all times.

I've come up with one way to solve this problem using `multiprocessing.Pool`, but the solution is quite brittle and relies on (AFAIK) undocumented features. It relies on the fact that the processes within the `Pool` are named in the format `FormPoolWorker-%d` where `%d` is a number between one and the number of processes in the pool. I take this value and mod it with the number of GPUs and that gives me a valid GPU id. However, it would be much nicer if I could somehow give the GPU id directly to each process, perhaps on initialization, instead of relying on the string format of the process names.

One thing I considered is that **if** the `initializer` and `initargs` parameters of `Pool.__init__`  allowed for a list of `initargs` so that each process could be initialized with a different set of arguments then the problem would be moot. Unfortunately that doesn't appear to work.

Can anybody recommend a more robust or pythonic solution to this problem?

**Hacky solution (Python 3.7):**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

def foo(filename):
    # Hacky way to get a GPU id using process name (format "ForkPoolWorker-%d")
    gpu_id = (int(current_process().name.split('-')[-1]) - 1) % 4

    # run processing on GPU <gpu_id>
    ident = current_process().ident
    print('{}: starting process on GPU {}'.format(ident, gpu_id))
    # ... process filename
    print('{}: finished'.format(ident))

pool = Pool(processes=4*2)

files = ['file{}.xyz'.format(x) for x in range(1000)]
for _ in pool.imap_unordered(foo, files):
    pass
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Where does GPU come into play? Your example uses CPUs.

Comment: The GPU processing would be invoked in the comment `# ... process filename`. I edited the post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out. It's actually quite simple. All we need to do is use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to manage the available GPU IDs. Start by initializing the `Queue` to contain 2 of each GPU ID, then `get` the GPU ID from the `queue` at the beginning of `foo` and `put` it back at the end.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process, Queue

NUM_GPUS = 4
PROC_PER_GPU = 2    

queue = Queue()

def foo(filename):
    gpu_id = queue.get()
    try:
        # run processing on GPU <gpu_id>
        ident = current_process().ident
        print('{}: starting process on GPU {}'.format(ident, gpu_id))
        # ... process filename
        print('{}: finished'.format(ident))
    finally:
        queue.put(gpu_id)

# initialize the queue with the GPU ids
for gpu_ids in range(NUM_GPUS):
    for _ in range(PROC_PER_GPU):
        queue.put(gpu_ids)

pool = Pool(processes=PROC_PER_GPU * NUM_GPUS)
files = ['file{}.xyz'.format(x) for x in range(1000)]
for _ in pool.imap_unordered(foo, files):
    pass
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I spent some time on your question and determined that I liked your original hack! I'm sure it will come in handy someday.

Comment: Hey, tnx for the example. I am however unclear regarding which part of the code exactly specifies the usage of GPUs, and not CPUs by default?

Comment: @davor korman As clarified by jodag, this takes place in the `# ... process filename` part, where code can be written that runs on GPU number `gpu_id`. The exact manner how the GPU is selected and invoked is not further specified since this depends on the use case, e.g. which library is being used to run code on the GPU.

Comment: I came across this recently (5 years later!) and used the queue pattern, but i've hit a snag: on ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.9.5 i get errors where CUDA cannot use the GPU. (note i set to 1 process per GPU so there shouldn't be a clash). but the error  below. wondered if anyone had come across/fixed: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1274] could not retrieve CUDA device count: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I have created a package [gpuMultiprocessing](https://gitlab.com/paloha/gpuMultiprocessing) which handles running a queue of processes on one or more GPUs. More precisely, it only handles the choice of a GPU by exploiting the functionality of multiprocessing package. It maps CPUid to GPUid and then it makes the GPUid available to the subprocess as an environment variable. So you can do something like `CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES=GPUid` inside the script. It also allows you to run multiple processes per GPU and keeps track of failed processes, in case they are not able to run, or in case they failed due to e.g. VRAM error. Probably not exactly what OP asks for but I though might be useful to somebody who comes here from google looking for GPU multiprocessing.

```py
# Example of running queue of 4 commands in parallel on 2 GPUs
# The number of CPUs must be equal or larger than the numbrer of GPUs!

import gpuMultiprocessing
gpu_id_list = [0,7] # Let's use these two GPUs   
command_queue = ['BATCHSIZE=16 python example-script.py',
                 'BATCHSIZE=32 python example-script.py',
                 'BATCHSIZE=64 python example-script.py',
                 'BATCHSIZ=80 python example-script.py']  # Typo on purpose

gpuMultiprocessing.queue_runner(command_queue, gpu_id_list,
                                env_gpu_name='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES',
                                processes_per_gpu=2, allowed_restarts=1)
```

This code snippet will run the commands from command_queue on GPUs 0 and 7 allowing for 2 processes per GPU at once. If some of the commands fail, it will try to restart them once any GPU is free. If it fails again, it will return a list containing the failed commands.